# Loading https://maps.google.cn in China require maps.gstatic.com?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The site I work on require google maps. Naturally there're issues with our clients in China. So, after some testing, I used 'https://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js'; it almost works, but somehow it fails on loading maps.gstatic.com.

Is it possible to load the google maps (in China) without having to load maps.gstatic.com - successfully?

Also, asking individual Chinese user to blacklist that domain in their browser - as suggested by some web blogs - is totally out of the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at the [Tencent/QQ JavaScript API V2](http://open.map.qq.com/doc_v2/)? I have never used it myself but it seems to be very complete too (quite similar to google) and will work fine for Chinese users for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation MrUpsidown, but using an alternative to google maps is also viable at this stage.

Comment: Google products have always had a hard time in China. Even accessing a Gmail account is a problem. Further to that, if you are not aware of it already, there is a big issue with displaced Google maps over China. Read more here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/ambcCIPTQiI

Comment: The link works fine for non-ssl version but it's not very helpful when you need https before the url...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this, but seems that *.gstatic.cn is the Chinese equivalent of *.gstatic.com. I confirmed that this domain name belongs to Google, and I saw reference to it in an API JS, but I didn't confirm whether the API is working for that.